# How to git push only the current branch when that is branched?

Tags: git

My git project currently looks like:

```
main
 \- branch1
     \- branch2
```

I put up a PR for branch1 that I'm waiting for teammates to review.

I also want to put up a PR for branch2, but only want to push the changes from that branch for review, and *not* branch1 since it adds a lot of noise.

I realize I'll need to rebase after branch1 is merged.

I know I can rebase branch2 onto main then push, but I'd ideally like to push "around" branch1 so that my local code still works.

Comment: The fundamental source of the problem is that Git pushes *commits*, not branches. A "branch" in this particular sense is largely meaningless: when you use `git push` for this particular case, you are usually *creating a new branch* in the target repository, but the new branch you're creating already has many commits. In this case the new branch `branch2` already has all the commits that are on its `branch1` that you already created.

Comment: Gerrit (as mentioned in [larsks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73536550/1256452)) works around this issue by creating a "Gerrit change-ID" for a collection of commits, grouping that set of commits into a semi-atomic entity. As you revise one of these semi-atomic-entities (group of commits), Gerrit gathers the updated ones into a new group and associates each group via the Gerrit change-ID. Gerrit itself takes over all the branch-name maintenance. That's why you push to `refs/for/<name>`, which is a "fake" reference.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's worth pointing out that the situation you're describing is
very common. It's also an area in which GitHub is notoriously bad
(compared to something like [Gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/), which is designed to work with
exactly this sort of workflow). What you have is a "stacked" or
"dependent" pull request, and searching for those terms will lead to
lots of interesting discussions and solutions.

If your feature branches live in the same repository as your target
branch, then you can make `branch2` target `branch1` instead.
Normally, when you open a pull request it will target the default
branch for the repository:

[image]

But you can choose to target another branch in the repository instead:

[image]

In this case, the pull request for `branch2` will only show the changes between `branch1` and `branch2` (which is exactly what you want).

---

If you are working with the fork-and-pull-request model, you're basically out of luck. Because the PR branches don't live in the main repository, they can't be the target of pull requests. In this case, `branch2` will always include the changes in `branch1` (unless it's actually independent and can be rebased directly on `main`).

People doing code reviews can use the commit filter to view changes from only specific commits, so they can choose to ignore commits that were actually part of `branch1`:

[image]

Comment: Actually GitHub is very good at this now. When the branch we're proposing to merge into is merged, the PR will change the merge target to match.

Comment: I think it's not, particular for fork-and-pull request workflows. It continues to be awful. As I said in this answer, it's fine if you happen to be working in the same repository as the target branches.

Comment: Ah, good point, yes. Ok so better than it was anyway.